# Google sheet : How to pre-authorise script/macro for shared sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am preparing a google sheet to be shared between a number of people.
I want to add some actions - script or macro - which will sort certain areas when the user clicks on a "button".

However, when I started doing this, sheets requests permission to run the script.

Is there a way to ensure that the script will "just run" and not start requesting further permissions ?

Comment: No```````.```````

Comment: Read about simple triggers and installed triggers in the official documentation.